# Except does not make correct intersection between 2 sets

Tags: sql

I want to get best sellers from march 2019, while excluding the top 3 sellers of january. I tried using except where first `SELECT` gives best sellers of march (all of them) and the second `SELECT` gives top 3 of january.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT fullname, SUM(sale) sales
FROM mytable
WHERE oredrdate BETWEEN '2019-03-01' AND '2019-03-31'
GROUP BY fullname
ORDER BY sales DESC) X

EXCEPT

SELECT * FROM (SELECT fullname, SUM(sale) sales
FROM mytable
WHERE oredrdate BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-31'
GROUP BY fullname
ORDER BY sales DESC
LIMIT 3) Y;
```

The problem is that `EXCEPT` does not intersect as I wished it would. What each `SELECT` returns and my desired output with data:

First `SELECT` returns:

```
fullname           sales
Tommy Williams     8320
Ryan Atkinson      7310
Petey Cruiser      6200
Anna Mull          5840
Gail Forcewind     4120
Paige Turner       3300
Bob Frapples       2100
...                ...
```

Seconds `SELECT` returns:

```
fullname           sales
Tommy Williams     9220
Anna Mull          8100
Greta Life         7891
```

Desired **OUTPUT**:

```
fullname           sales
Ryan Atkinson      7310
Petey Cruiser      6200
Gail Forcewind     4120
Paige Turner       3300
Bob Frapples       2100
...                ...
```

How should I change my code to achieve this?

Comment: This query is incorrect. Probably MySQL. `SELECT fullname, sales .. GROUP BY fullname` - there is no aggregate function for `sales`

Comment: try not in fullname for the inner query

Comment: you're right, I made a mistake while making minimal verifiable code. I have aggregate func in my code

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: im using snowflake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a LEFT JOIN where you exclude the matching rows:

```
SELECT X.* 
FROM (
  SELECT fullname, SUM(sale) sales
  FROM mytable
  WHERE oredrdate BETWEEN '2019-03-01' AND '2019-03-31'
  GROUP BY fullname
) X LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT fullname, SUM(sale) sales
  FROM mytable
  WHERE oredrdate BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-31'
  GROUP BY fullname
  ORDER BY sales DESC
  LIMIT 3
) Y ON Y.fullname = X.fullname
WHERE Y.fullname IS NULL
ORDER BY X.sales DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
SELECT fullname, SUM(sales) AS total
FROM mytable
WHERE oredrdate BETWEEN '2019-03-01' AND '2019-03-31'
  AND fullname NOT IN (SELECT fullname, SUM(sales) AS total
                       FROM mytable
                       WHERE oredrdate BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-31'
                         AND fullname IS NOT NULL
                       GROUP BY fullname
                       ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 3)
GROUP BY fullname
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

I would group by some kind of unique column like employee_id, there is possibility that two persons could have the same name.

Comment: in inner SELECT you meant to order by total?

Comment: hmm, let's say that fullname is actually: `CONCAT(firstname+ ' ' + lastname) AS fullname`. Then this should be defined in both SELECT or just the outer?

Comment: @user3053452 These queries are not correlated, so it has to be defined in both places

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `EXCEPT` is considering *both* the name and the amount columns.  It is unlikely that the second would match.

One way to write this is:

```
WITH jan3 as (
      SELECT TOP (3) fullname, SUM(sale) as sales
      FROM mytable
      WHERE orderdate >= '2019-01-01' AND
            orderdate < '2019-02-01'
      GROUP BY fullname
      ORDER BY sales DESC
     )
SELECT m.fullname, SUM(m.sale) as sales
FROM mytable m
WHERE m.orderdate >= '2019-03-01' AND
      m.orderdate < '2019-04-01' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM jan3
                  WHERE jan3.fullname = m.fullname
                 )
GROUP BY fullname
ORDER BY sales DESC;
```

Note that this changes the date comparisons to use `>=` and `<`.  This is considered a best practice, because it works for dates and datetime (timestamp) values.

There are other ways of writing this using only a single aggregation.  For instance:

```
WITH s as (
      SELECT m.fullname,
             SUM(CASE WHEN m.orderdate < '2019-02-01' THEN m.sale END) as sales_jan,
             SUM(CASE WHEN m.orderdate >= '2019-03-01' THEN m.sale END) as sales_mar
      FROM mytable m
      WHERE m.orderdate >= '2019-01-01' AND
            m.orderdate < '2019-04-01'
     )
SELECT s.*
FROM (SELECT s.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sales_jan DESC) as seqnum_jan
      FROM s
     ) s
WHERE seqnum_jan > 3
ORDER BY s.sales_mar;
```

Comment: Where do you get top 3 sellers in your first example?